# Accessing the Request.Content in the new ASP.NET vnext web api way of doing things?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have searched high and low for this one and can't seem to find a way of accessing the Request.Content in an MVC web api. I basically am trying to create a File Service to and from Azure Blob and Table storage (table for storing metadata about the file, blob for the actual file)....

I was converting the steps in the following link, but this is where I have come unstuck

the back end I have working but can't find a way of the new unified controller passing a fileobject from json post through to the service! Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as always... or am I just going about this the wrong way?

[Article here....](http://arcware.net/upload-and-download-files-with-web-api-and-azure-blob-storage/)

**UPDATE:** so to clarify, what I am trying to do in the new MVC 6 (where you no longer have an apicontroller to inherit from) is to access a file that has been uploaded to the api from a JSON post. That is the long and short of what I am trying to achieve.
I am trying to use the article based on the old Web API which uses the Request.Content to access it, however even if I use the WebAPIShim which they provide I still come unstuck with other objects or properties that are no longer available so I'm wondering if I need to approach it a different way, but either way, all I am trying to do is to get a file from a JSON post to a MVC 6 Web api and pass that file to my back end service....

ANY IDEAS?

Comment: You mention Request.Context in your title but Request.Content in your post, which are specifying? Can you more clearly describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @EstebanFelix well spotted.... that was a typo, I've updated the question with a little more context around what it is I'm actually trying to achieve! Any pointers greatly appreciated, I realise I may be going about this the wrong way in the new world way of doing things.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example without relying on model binding.

You can always find the request data in `Request.Body`, or use `Request.Form` to get the request body as a form.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    if (Request.Form.Files != null && Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        var contentType = file.ContentType;

        using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                // do what you want with memoryStream.ToArray()
            }
        }       
    }

    return new JsonResult(new { });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing in your request is a File you can use the `IFormFile` class in your action:

```
    public FileDetails UploadSingle(IFormFile file)
    {
        FileDetails fileDetails;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
            fileDetails = new FileDetails
            {
                Filename = parsedContentDisposition.FileName,
                Content = fileContent
            };
        }

        return fileDetails;
    }
```